# undefined variable in model method (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

this is my JadwalKlinik method:

```
public function scopeByParams($query, $params)
{
    if( isset($params) ){
        $query->whereHas('user', function($q){
            $q->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$params.'%');
        });
    }

    return $query;
}
```

$params in query function (line 5) is undefined, why ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the keyword `use` with your closure

```
$query->whereHas('user', function($q) use ($params){
    $q->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$params.'%');
});
```